# Get the value inside of url("")

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying with the following Regex:

`[^url("](.*(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif))`

But I only need the `value` inside of `url("` `")`

Example:

- from: `url("34eb1bd00e8e0e4f59a33f654edc483a.jpg")`
- extract: `34eb1bd00e8e0e4f59a33f654edc483a.jpg`

Comment: Not clear. What are example inputs, and expected output for each?

Comment: `match(/^(url\(").*("\))$/)`  I just wanted to get the `url(" ")` in my example: `url("`34eb1bd00e8e0e4f59a33f654edc483a.jpg`")` Is it possible to get the in betweens?

Comment: So for input `url("34eb1bd00e8e0e4f59a33f654edc483a.jpg")` you want to extract `34eb1bd00e8e0e4f59a33f654edc483a.jpg`?

Comment: yes i'd like to get the value inside or the in between `url(" ")`

Comment: Please update your question with clarifying details so that we can help you.

Comment: I helped clarifying the question. A moderator now should re-open this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const str = 'background: #fbfbfb url("34eb1bd00e8e0e4f59a33f654edc483a.jpg");';
const regex = /^.*?url\(['"]?([^'"\)]*)['"]?\).*$/;
let result = str.replace(regex, '$1');
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
34eb1bd00e8e0e4f59a33f654edc483a.jpg
```

Explanation:

- `^` - anchor at start
- `.*?` - non-greedy scan
- `url\(` - literal `url(`
- `['"]?` - optional quotes
- `([^'"\)]*)` - capture group with everything up to a quote or `)`
- `['"]?` - optional quotes
- `\)` - literal `)`
- `.*$` - match all to end of string

Comment: @Ayaka: Does this fit your needs? Any questions? Care to accept the answer?

Comment: @Ayaka: See gray check mark next to the question.

Comment: I like very much you're expression. It's very cool. Points for you XD

Answer (score 0):

I hope this goes acording your need's

You can use this pattern for get all between in url("") OR url(''):

```
(?<=url\(("|')).*?(?=("|')\))
```

Here is te regex test: [URL](https://regexr.com/5n8tu)

And if ypu want get all that only have '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif':

```
(?<=url\(("|')).*?\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)(?=("|')\))
```

Here is te regex test: [URL Img](https://regexr.com/5n8u4)